# Correct HTTP verb to use for a business rules validation endpoint in Web API

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the below Web API controller. Its sole responsibility is to validate the incoming document against a set of business rules and return a result. Which is the correct HTTP verb to use for this controller action?

```
//[Http<???>]
public IActionResult ValidateBusinessRules([FromBody BusinessDocument document)
{
  var result = ValidateBusinessRules(document);
  return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: I think BedRequest (401) would be best - when something goes wrong. But on the other hand, I think it is not a RESTfull endpint. In my opinion, the best way is to prepare the end-point with validation at the very beginning and with a certain business logic (performed after validation passed)

Comment: `FromBody` works with POST or PUT

Comment: @mirt my question is which HTTP verb to use i.e. GET, POST, PUT etc. Also I need to return an object containing the result of each validation rule which is fairly complex in structure. Can’t just return return BadRequest

Comment: @ErshadNozari, you can also return BedRequest with an object.

Comment: @ErshadNozari Do you use this method to validate data from form and if it is valid you save the data using another endpoint?

Comment: @mirt correct validating data from the form. Can either be ok or contain multiple validation errors in the result object. The response is sent back to the caller (another web api) which performs other operations based on the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[FromBody]` explicitly tells the model binder to check the request body for data to bind. And since only certain request allow a body then it means that it works with POST or PUT.

POST would be the default verb to use in this scenario. Taking model state into consideration the action can look like this

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ValidateBusinessRules([FromBody] BusinessDocument document) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        var result = ValidateBusinessRules(document);            
        if(result.IsValid) { //assuming result has a flag
            return Ok(result);
        }
        return BadRequest(result);//assuming result provides relevant details.
    }
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

That way the status of the response can provide some relevant feedback about the request made.

Comment: I have POST at the moment, but didn’t think it was the correct verb to use as POST is meant to be used for resource creation, no?

Comment: @ErshadNozari No. POST is meant to be used when one of the other verbs is not applicable. From the HTTP spec: "The POST method requests that the target resource process the
   representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's
   own specific semantics." https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.3

Answer (score 1):

One could argument that *POST* should only be used for creating a new entity but as *GET* is not designed to send data through the request body and the other verbs (*PUT* = update entity, *DELETE* = remove entity) don't give you a better option I would say it's OK to use *POST* for scenarios where you need to get some data from the server and need to send data in the request body.

I would therefore recommend you to use *POST* here

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ValidateBusinessRules([FromBody] BusinessDocument document)
{
  var result = ValidateBusinessRules(document);
  return Ok(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this endpoint to validate data from form, and then you want to save them through another endpoint, I think, that the best solution would be something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("documents")]
    public IActionResult ValidateBusinessRules([FromBody] BusinessDocument document)
    {

        var result = ValidateBusinessRules(document);
        if (!result.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(result);
        }

        var document = _documentService.Save(document);
        return Ok(document);
    }
```

For me it is odd to use POST if you don't want to create new resource.

Comment: No resource is created in this instance. I do agree, it seems odd to use POST if no resource is created and hence my question.